# Ajustando o site para qualquer tela

Tags: css, media-queries

Bom galera, to tentando aprender melhor sobre o redimensionamento do site aplicado a qualquer tela. Já li alguns tutoriais na internet e pelo jeito não consegui fazer tudo direito, porque aqui no meu teste eu aplico as @medias só que ao entrar no site em questao por um dispositivo de tela pequena o site não redimensiona, ele abre com as configurações de uma tela maior doq a dele de fato.

O codigo que to usando é esse dai

```
<html>
<title>nada</title>
<head>﻿ 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<style>

*{padding:0px; margin:0px}
/* Resluções */
@media (min-width: 240px) {
  .box{width: auto; background:#333; height:100px}
}

@media (min-width: 270px) {
  .box{width: auto; background:#6C0; height:100px}
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .box{width: auto; background:##90F; height:100px}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .box{width: auto; background:#F00; height:100px}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .box{width: auto; background:#C00; height:100px}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podem ver eu criei apenas uma unica div chamada de box, essa div é só pra teste, e se tudo ocorresse bem essa div ia mudar de cor conforme o tamanho do navegador. Quando testo isso em um navegador normal se eu diminuir o browse a div muda sua cor de acordo com o tamanho, porem no celular ele não obedece essa regra. O que está errado? ou o que está faltando?

Comment: Sugiro uma lida no link abaixo pois tem material bem legal relacionado ao que você precisa fazer (mais do que um monte de tutorial de media querie, aqui tem conteúdo conceitual e outras dicas indo além meramente de css e js). Link sugerido: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/#b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve-se ao fato de você não estar indicando de que se deve checar o tamanho mínimo, para checar o tamanho da tela o código correto é esse:

```
@media only screen and (...)
```